# How to exchange data on different networks using sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I know this was already asked but the previous questions didn't help. I'm trying to send some data using sockets. Specifically I'm using my laptop as server and a Linux emulator (Termux) on my smartphone as a client. Here below you can see the two Python codes. For the server:

```
import socket
HOST = ''
PORT = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen()
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(data)
    s.close()
```

And for the client:

```
import socket
HOST = ''
PORT = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
s.close()
```

When I'm connected to the same WiFi and in HOST (in both codes) I put the IP I see from ipconfig (192.168.---.---) everything works. It also works if in the HOST of the server I put 0.0.0.0.

However, when I put the IP of the machine (that I can see on https://whatismyipaddress.com/) and instead of using the WiFi I use the phone connection I get: `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection Refused`.

Can someone explain me how can I connect client and server when the networks are different? I have been stuck with this for a while.

I also tried to open a port on the Firewall following [this procedure](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html) and put it in the code instead of 5555 but still it didn't work.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Port forwarding issues maybe?

Comment: I also tried using that but it doesn't work if the networks are different (it works if I'm connected to the same WiFi with both devices)

Comment: if you are on different networks this is a port forwarding issue, the ip you see on whatmyip isnt YOUR ip its your NETWROKs IP, you have to configure your router to forward incoming communication to your LOCAL address

Comment: You should forward your router's port 5555 incoming connections to the server machine local IP and port. Do you have access/permissions to modify your router's config?

Comment: @danlor I just checked and I don't have the permissions. So it's impossible for me to do it I guess.

Comment: Mmm...I'm afraid that it will be a difficult task to accomplish then. Is there any chance of getting the permissions? If not, you can take a look over UPnP, maybe you're lucky and your router has it enabled by default...